# How long is a unit of distance?

Tags: league-of-legends

I play the character called Tristana in League of Legend.
Tristana have an ability called "BUSTER SHOT" (Tristana's ultimate).

> **BUSTER SHOT:** 
>   Tristana fires a massive cannonball at an enemy unit. This deals 300 / 400 / 500 (+150% of ability power) magic damage and knocks surrounding units back 600 / 800 / 1000 distance.

**What does the numeric value of distance in League of Legends, as described in this ability, equal to what visible range in the game?**

In other RTS games, like StarCraft 2 - it's a nice thing to know when you engage in combat. To be startegic in your advance against an enemy, and your teamwork regarding League of Legends.

If I knew what the "distance" is translated into on the screen, I could be more effective in positioning my teammates for the final-blow on an enemy hero.

Comment: honestly judging skill and AA distance comes with experience, i wish there was a way to have distances show up next to the target.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A rule of thumb is that Teemo is roughly 100 units wide.  So, for your example, you could mentally translate the Buster shot ability to:

> **BUSTER SHOT**: Tristana fires a massive cannonball at an enemy unit.
>   This deals 300 / 400 / 500 (+150% of ability power) magic damage and
>   knocks surrounding units back 6 / 8 / 10 Teemos in distance.

Comment: This answer is probably the best for trying to visualize distance in league. I heard this explanation back in season 1 when I was still new to the game and it is by far the easiest to use to judge distance during the course of a match. Eventually you won't need to do this anymore as you will have become accustomed to the champions you play.

Comment: You can technically use any other well-known distance as an estimation tool.  Flash is 400 units, ward cast range is 600, Ignite cast range is 600, etc.  As @Ravekner said, you'll eventually get an intuition for the ranges of spell you use frequently.

Comment: This is true as well but can change as riot changes the game. Flash itself has been nerfed at least once to my knowledge and all abilities and spells are prone to changes by Riot as the game evolves and new mechanics are introduced.

Comment: Good point.  Teemo's model size is far less likely to change than flash/wards/ignite/etc.

Comment: I like the way you discribe "Knocks surrounding units back in Teemos". Teemos will in the future be the new form of messurering distance.

Comment: Another good range to remember is turret range (775) ie: almost 8 Teemos! The sight range is a bit larger (1095) or 11 Teemos!

Comment: HAHAHA +1 for using Teemos as a unit of measurement! My friend who streams has also done this for dmg, ie. "That guy does more than 6 Teemos per second of damage". You, sir, just made my day."

Comment: Here's the origin/source for the Teemo unit of measurement: http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1566567

Answer (score 6):

Basic attack range of Ashe will give you the best idea. Ashe can hit units from 600 distance away. In the picture below, the blue line is 600 distance long. That is the range of buster shot's knockback at level 1. At level 2 it is one-third longer and at max level it is two-thirds longer.

(Image taken at 1920x1080 zoomed out as much as possible)
[image: 600]

Comment: I do not know if this is 100% accurate as I remember being told once that AA units and spell units are different. This would mean that 600 attack range does not equal 600 spell range. I will see if I can find a source to confirm.

Comment: @AdamP Try to find that. I haven't heard of it but it could be true.

Comment: The only thing I can come up with to support this idea would be that you and your target can move after the casting of a spell that would give the illusion of said spell having a larger range than it is listed having. The only abilities this would not really apply to would be skillshots though some have a slightly larger range than you would think.(example- Anivia's Q has a slightly larger hit range than the spell shows as it detonates at max range, probably worth about an additional 50 units of range in a circle around its detonation spot)

Comment: Adam is right, because spell cast range is calculated from center of casting character model to center of receiving character model; whereas AA units is from edge of attacking character model to end edge of receiving character model.

Answer (score 4):

You can also hover your mouse over the Attack Damage amount from the statistics right at the bottom, the game will draw a circle around your character which determines the auto-attack range your champion has.

Answer (score 4):

A few pointers:

- Melee attacks have a 130 range.
- Caster minions have a 600 range (same as Ryze's spells since the last patch).
- Your movement speed is equal to the distance you can cover every second.